# mod_rewrite redirect login page

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, mediawiki

I've got mediawiki running on my server, and am using external authentication to log users in. Because of this, I'm using mod_rewrite to redirect users from the wiki log in page to the default log in page for symfony. The url that I am trying to match is this:

```
http://SERVER/wiki/index.php?title=Special:UserLogin
```

And the page I'm trying to send them to is:

```
http://SERVER/login
```

which should actually go to

```
http://SERVER/index.php/login
```

The .htaccess file I'm using is this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wiki/index.php$
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^title=Special:UserLogin
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^GET$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ../login? [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

But for some reason, it errors out to

```
 Empty module and/or action after parsing the URL "/local/www/SERVER/web/index.php/login"
```

Any ideas on what is going wrong? Much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks to a coworker, I figured it out, but wanted to post the answer here in case anyone was curious. The .htaccess file was in the wiki folder, which was inside the web folder. the ".." I had in front of 

    /login?

was the problem and was sending in back one extra directory. Removing those fixed the problem.

Comment: make it an answer rather than comment and accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to a coworker, I figured it out, but wanted to post the answer here in case anyone was curious. The .htaccess file was in the wiki folder, which was inside the web folder. the ".." I had in front of /login? was the problem and was sending in back one extra directory. Removing those fixed the problem.